# Play the events of YouTube player

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I use Xcode Swift 7 and 2.
I want to know how to listen to the YouTube player events. I am using the  YouTube API. I would like to know more precisely when is it that my player is finished loading.

Comment: Use `YTPlayerView`'s  `didChangeToState` delegate and check for `kYTPlayerStatePlaying` or `kYTPlayerStatePaused` values.

Comment: Can you make me an example, because I've tried it, but it does not work ...

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have a project using this at the moment to run tests, I just remembered the way it was supposed to work and made a quick comment about it.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway ! ;)

Comment: @hugo_082: There's an example project on GitHub. Here's the relevant code from it where the delegate is set and used: [Link](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Project/youtube-player-ios-example/youtube-player-ios-example/SingleVideoViewController.m)

Comment: This example is write with Objective-C ... I work with Swift ... :/

Comment: If you're gonna be using the iOS helper library, you should be using Objective-C to save yourself some headache later. Or you could try [this library](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/) I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Swift 2.1, Xcode 7.1, and Youtube API v3.

I found this tutorial quite helpful: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

If you're using cocoapods it should be even easier but I just manually copied over the `.h` and `.m` and created a Bridging-Header.

To setup the delegate is quite easy.  First you have to tell your VC to conform to the `YTPlayerViewDelegate` like so:

[image]

Then make an outlet for your `YTPlayerView` and call `[playerViewNameHere].delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad`.

You can implement `didChangeToSate` like this:

```
// MARK: YTPlayerDelegate methods

func playerView(playerView: YTPlayerView!, didChangeToState state: YTPlayerState) {
    switch(state) {
    case YTPlayerState.Unstarted:
        print("Unstarted")
        break
    case YTPlayerState.Queued:
        print("Ready to play")
        break
    case YTPlayerState.Playing:
        print("Video playing")
        break
    case YTPlayerState.Paused:
        print("Video paused")
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

I only get the play and pause notifications when the fullscreen view opens though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Did you find how to get the `Unstarted` and the `Queued` notifications?